# Excel forcing Text NumberFormat on a cell with Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, number-formatting

I am trying to store a formula in a cell.  The cell has a `NumberFormat` set to `"@"` i.e. Text. When I do:

```
TargetSheet.Cells(Row, Col).Formula = "=A7"
```

And A7 has in it `"1805R03-01"` I get `"=A7"` displayed in the in the cell.
Even though I think you should be allowed to define formulas for a Text formatted field if you set it through the `Formula` property, I changed the code to:

```
(1)  TargetSheet.Cells(Row, Col).NumberFormat = "General"
(2)  TargetSheet.Cells(Row, Col).Formula = "=A7"
```

And that palatially got me what I wanted, as now my cell displays the correct value of `"1805R03-01"` but the number format is set by Excel again to "@" so that if I hit enter on that cell the display returns to `"=A7"`.  I could re-add Line `(1)` as and additional Line `(3)` in my code above, but that just means that I will stop the conversion of my formula back to text one time, hitting enter twice on that cell still results in `"=A7"`.  How do I stop Excel from forcing the Text number format on a cell?  The cell displays correctly when I manually return the format for it to `"General"` so a Text number format is not needed.

Comment: So after auto-formatting, Excel no longer treats the `A7` in the formula as a cell reference, but instead as a literal string `"A7"`? If cell `A7`'s number format is text, try setting it to something else (even something technically wrong like `0` just to see). Then re-enter the formula in `cells(row, col)` and check if you get different results. Another thing you could try is `TargetSheet.Cells(Row, Col).Formula = "=""""&A7"` and see if the null string interferes with the auto-formatting. There might be an application setting that you could toggle via code to turn auto-formatting on/off.

Comment: It actually treats the whole formula `"=A7"` not just `"A7"` as a literal string.  And you actually found the solution, when I turn the source cell formatting to `General` (it was Text before) then the problem does not happen anymore.  How do I mark a comment as the solution?

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer with some extra detail, if you want to mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cell `A7`'s number format is `text`, try setting it to `general`. Then re-enter the formula in `cells(row, col)` and check if you get different results.

Dependent cells (in the context of formula auditing) seem to inherit the NumberFormat of their precedents -- unless the precedent cell's NumberFormat is `general`.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this helps, but I encountered the similar problem in the past, where Excel would automatically switch back the numberformat according to its own judgement.

So what i did was this: say I have two columns

```
A          B
abc       123
asuh      412
auw       9781
ija       124
```

I would set the number of another column, column C, as general

```
Range("C:C").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "general"
```

And then copy A or B into it. In your case it would be to automate the code onto it.

And it didnt turn back into either text or number again.
For me at least.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good suggestion and is kind of the same answer as @chillin gave in a comment to my question, to make the source cells not be Text as excel seems to want to copy the NumberFormat from the source cells along with the value.